# make a title for <image> of SVG

Tags: html, image, d3.js, svg

I was trying to put a title for a img of SVG.
The title is at the bottom of the pic.
The code goes like:

```
<svg>
  <image>
</svg>
```

How to realize this without using  inner ?
And I also wanna make it based on *D3.js* , if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: As in, you want it so when the mouse hovers over it, it gives a rollover title? Does `svg title="foobar"` or `image="foobar"` yielded any success or notable behavior?

Comment: you mean `<svg title="foobar"> or <svg image="foobar">` ?

Comment: I meant `<svg title="foobar">` or `<image title="foobar">`. My bad. Have you tried that, and if so, what behavior did you get?

Comment: nothing changed. only the pic there.

Comment: sorry. my bad. There is a small tag around the cursor like tooltip. But that's not what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SVG elements, you don't use a title attribute. You have to use a `<title>` element, which you put inside the element to which it applies.

```html
<svg>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/" width="300" height="150">
        <title>foobar</title>
    </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: one more question. Can i change <title>'s shape by CSS ? I tried, but not worked.

Comment: No you can't.  It's just like the HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a piece of text below the image.  Put the text y position = image height + a little padding.  Or you could put the y position a bit less than the image height and it would land on top of the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- from this website http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html -->
<svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

    <image x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" id="HVACEast" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://some.site.com/image.png" opacity="0.4" style="pointer-events: none"/>
    <text stroke-width=".05" fill="#66CCB2" x="5" y="105" font-family="serif" font-size="5pt">IMAGE TITLE</text>
</svg>
```

Or use tspan for the text.

```
<text>
    <tspan x="5" y="105" font-size="5pt" fill="yellow">Image</tspan>
    <tspan x="5" y="108" font-size="5pt" stroke="blue">Title</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: That is a way indeed. But <text> cannot wrap the word easily， right? Do you have another way or a workaround there?

Comment: SVG 1.1 has no text wrap.  You can use tspan to give you the wrapping styled text.  It is a bit more work. See edit to original answer.